# Using MS Excel, how to round date/time format value to nearest 5 minute?

Tags: excel, date

I have a column with custom format (as the data comes from DB) as "m/d/yyyy h:mm". How can I add a formula to another column next to this one so I get result rounded up/down to nearest 5 minute value?

I want result in same format as "m/d/yyyy h:mm".

So for example:

6/20/2016 16:02 should be converted to-> 6/20/2016 16:05

6/20/2016 16:50 should be converted to-> 6/20/2016 16:50

I can use `=MROUND(F24,5/(60*24))` but it gives output in mm:ss.0 format but I need it in "m/d/yyyy h:mm" format.

Comment: The formula works for me, just make sure the cell is formatted properly.

Comment: It does. Foolish of me. Thank you Scott. I wanted to mark the question as answered and you response as the answer but don't see option for that.

Comment: Your formula **`=MROUND(F24,5/(60*24))`** will convert **`6/20/2016 16:02`** to **`6/20/2016 16:00`** and not **`6/20/2016 16:05`**.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in column A. Just use **`CEILING`** function like this:

```
=CEILING(A2,"00:05")
```

Here is the data that I've used:

[image]

Place the formula in cell B2 and drag it down.